# drope table mechanism in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

When a table is dropped using a simple DROP statement, SQL performs some more operations simultaneously, select all the valid operations?

```
a.  Removes all rows from the table
b.  Drops all the table's indexes
c.  Removes all dependent views
d.  Removes all dependent procedures
```

Comment: no , i dont get the problem that what can be currect ans? . If you know please give answer sir?

Comment: i saw this on eLance, the LAMP test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DROP will do (a) and (b), but not (c) and (d) which can lead to trouble later if care isn't taken.